# The plus logo does not change when the menu is unfolded

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

I added the following line to my style sheet, to display a plus when the mower is not unfolded.

```
#block-menuprincipal li.dropdown > a[aria-expanded=false] i:before {
  content: '\f055';
}
```

The logo works but when I load my page, the first logo is a plus and the second is a "minus".
The menu is not unfolded, both logo should be "plus".

[image]

If I unfold the two menus and fold them, the logos are "plus".

Why is the second logo a "minus" if I reload the page?

[image]

[image]

After unfolding and folding the menu, it works. But if I reload the page I have the same problem.

[image]

Here is my menu block :

```
<nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="block-navigationprincipale-menu" id="block-navigationprincipale">
   <ul class="menu nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="expanded dropdown open">
         <a href="/boutique" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Boutiques</a>
            <ul class="menu dropdown-menu">
               <li>
                  <a href="/boutique" data-drupal-link-system-path="boutique"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Boutiques</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="/produit" data-drupal-link-system-path="produit"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Produits</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="/service" data-drupal-link-system-path="service"><i class="fa fa-sign-language fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Services</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="expanded dropdown">
         <a href="/groupe" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Groupes</a>
            <ul class="menu dropdown-menu">
               <li>
                  <a href="/groupe" data-drupal-link-system-path="groupe"><i class="fa fa-users fa-mg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Groupes</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="/annonce" data-drupal-link-system-path="annonce"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Annonces</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="/article" data-drupal-link-system-path="article"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Articles</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="/discussion" data-drupal-link-system-path="discussion"><i class="fa fa-comments fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Discussions</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="/recette" data-drupal-link-system-path="recette"><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Recettes</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="/itineraire" data-drupal-link-system-path="itineraire"><i class="fa fa-map-signs fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Itinéraires</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="/evenement" data-drupal-link-system-path="evenement"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Événements</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/profil" data-drupal-link-system-path="profil"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Profils</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you provide HTML structure of your menu so that we can check what's wrong with the CSS?

Comment: Ok, I checked on your website. The problem is that if you will inspect the second li of that menu the anchor tag don't have aria-expanded="false" attribute added to it. So you have to add that programmatically there.

Comment: @Bharat I use drupal 8 how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, If you are using D8, then it will be a bit hard to add that attribute. So we should try to fix this by CSS only.
Can you replace your CSS with what I am providing below

```
    #block-menuprincipal li.dropdown > a i:before {
       content: '\f055';
    }

    #block-menuprincipal li.dropdown > a[aria-expanded=true] i:before {
       content: '\f056';
    }
```